# How to install Ubuntu on Microsoft ARM Dev kit?

Tags: system-installation, arm, arm64

Microsoft recently unveiled its [ARM Dev kit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/dev-kit).

This computer has 32GB RAM and a Qualcomm Snapdragon 8cx Gen 3 processor, and it is way more powerful than a Raspberry Pi.

How to install Ubuntu on it?

Comment: I think that I would start off trying to get the image for RPi 4's to work, but am just guessing,  I will follow your thread.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I don't know the answer (I don't have the device either- will buy if Ubuntu supports it, maybe in a year or so :) )

Comment: Someone tried, but it was a largely unsuccessful attempt https://blog.alexellis.io/linux-on-microsoft-dev-kit-2023/

Comment: Someone managed to get most components working. https://github.com/merckhung/linux_on_arm64_laptop#microsoft-dev-kit-2023